# Refresh data in PowerBI to bring in new columns

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I'm using PowerBI Desktop Version: 2.87.762.0 64-bit (November 2020).
Reading data from ADLS Gen 2.

I have been trying to refresh the data in PowerBI to bring in new columns but can’t seem to do it.

- I have data on ADLS which I imported into PowerBI.
- Now in the source ADLS table I have additional columns.
- I would like to refresh the data in PowerBI for it to read the latest tables and hence bring in the new columns.
- I have tried refreshing but it doesn’t seem to work.
- Tried clicking on “Refresh” in the “Report” view – (which reading online will not work)
- Tried refreshing in the “Power Query Mode”. (Steps shown in the figure below, which I think should have worked)
- But the new columns don’t show up in PowerBI.
- I can download the data from ADLS and confirm that new columns are present.

What am I missing?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a few things you can check:

1. can you see the new columns in the power query editor? try a go a few steps back in transform history.
   fx. Sometimes if you "expand" a column it will not add new columns and you will need to add those afterwards ie. do the expand-transform again.
   btw. the "Refresh All" in the power query editor is only refreshing the example data.
2. if you see the data in the power query editor, try and hit refresh in the pbi editor.
3. if there is no data in the power query editor. use another tool to look at the source to confirm that the data i actually present in the stream that pbi has access to.

Comment: Thanks. The first step solved the problem: "try a go a few steps back in transform history." In the PowerQuery "Applied Steps" I went to the first step "Source" clicked on "Binary" in the "Content" column to expand the column again and with that when it expanded, I could see the new columns.