# Older Power-BI pbix using a SharePoint-Online list that has had new fields added

Tags: powerbi, sharepoint-online

I have a Power-BI dashboard that was created some time ago. It’s data source is a SharePoint-Online list. Since the Power-BI dashboard was created, several new fields have been added to the SharePoint list. Now I am being asked to add a new page to the dashboard that reports on those new fields. However, I have not found a way to get the existing Power-BI list/dataset to show the new fields.

Refreshing the data does refresh the values, but refresh does not add the new fields.

I’ve spend the last 4 hours looking on the internet for a solution. The only thing I have been able to do so far is to attach the list again with a different name- the new fields DO show up when I do this. (I can’t just replace the older Power-BI list/dataset because there have been several calculated columns and measures added.)

I can work with this and create the report, but is this the only way? It doesn’t seem like it should be.
Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

(I'm using Power BI April 2021 and Sharepoint Online)

Comment: Have you tried refreshing the preview in the query editor, not just refreshing the data?

Comment: I wasn't sure how to do that. But, I looked it up and found: "There's almost no difference between the two buttons. The refresh button in design view will get the latest data by refreshing all visuals in your report. The refresh all button will refresh preview data of all queries. Both of them will request the latest data to data source." https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Refresh-Preview-All-power-query-or/td-p/998908

Comment: If you go through the steps in the power query connection, and refresh the preview,it should show the added columns since it was last done. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64925436/refresh-data-in-powerbi-to-bring-in-new-columns

Comment: @Jon I looked at the steps suggested. The 1st step asks"can you see the new columns in the power query editor? " The answer is no. None of the new columns are showing up there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it looks like there's no good answer to this issue. I found that adding another instance of the reference Sharepoint list, that included the new columns, did work (however inelegant). That seems to be the best direct answer for times when the older pbix file must continue to be used.

What I ended up doing, though, was to create a new separate pbix file which included the latest version of the Sharepoint List. This was the best solution for my organization since it will allow us to be more focused on the specific manufacturing processes involved.

Thanks to @Jon and @Alejandro for their efforts to help!

Answer (score -1):

If you have access to PowerAutomate you could refresh the dataset creating a flow so that given a certain time (say, once or twice a day) the dataset gets refreshed with the new created items.

Otherwise if you are working with the service version of Power BI you can program a refresh of the dataset directly from the workspace going to the settings of the dataset. You would have to have a gateway set for that which could be in personal mode or not.

Also if you want to update the data in the service version you could do it manually too in the workspace.

Comment: Thanks for responding, however, the OP is not asking about dataset refreshes or scheduling them, they are asking why since the report was created they cannot see new columns added since then, and how to update the metadata